# A nested array is defined in one line, then undefined right after (javascript)

Tags: javascript, p5.js, minimax

So I am kind of new to the minimax algorithm. I know what it is supposed to do and how it works, but I am struggling on the implementation of the algorithm on a game of tic tac toe. I followed through the video of codingtrain writing the algorithm, and also referenced his original code. However, when i finish calling the minimax function within the minimax function, i cannot revert the board. The following code is my minimax function.

```
function minimax(board, depth, isMaximizing) {
  let result = checkWinner();
  if (result != null) { // if the game is over return the scores and no more minimax needed
    return scores[result];
  }

  if (isMaximizing) {
    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    let move;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == "") { // is spot avaliable
          board[i][j] = ai; // ai takes spot
          let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, false); // call minimax on the current board
          board[i][j] = "";
          bestScore = max(score, bestScore); // looking for the highest score
        }
      }
    }
    return move;
  } else {
    let bestScore = Infinity;
    let move;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == "") { // is spot avaliable
          board[i][j] = human; // human takes spot
          let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, true); // call minimax on the current board
          board[i][j] = "";
          bestScore = min(score, bestScore); // looking for the lowest score
        }
      }
    }
    return move;
  }
}
```

I get the error "TypeError: board[i] is undefined" on the line `board[i][j] = "";`, and i am confused because i could set it to ai and human on the lines beforehand. For reference, [this](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/0zyUhZdJD) is codingtrain's code, and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trKjYdBASyQ&t=1419s) is codingtrain's video of him writing this code, explaining what it does.

If I do not provide enough information please don't get mad this is my first question on stack overflow and im not sure what else to add.

Comment: You return move but never set it to anything.

Comment: `move = { i, j };` is missing.

Comment: i was supposed to return a score in the minimax function, so i changed `return move` to `return score`. this also means that `move = {i, j}` is not needed. Although that does fix a problem, the original error doesnt go away

Comment: `for (i = 0; ...` congratulations! You just birthed a global variable that will be shared across each instance of your recursive function!

Comment: i changed it to `for (let i = 0;...1` and it worked thanks so much :)